# Why does my zend application work on my localhost but fail on my server with 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception'?

Tags: zend-framework

I created a zend application and it works fine on localhost, but I can't make it work on server, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message
'Plugin by name 'ServerURL' was not found in the registry; 

used paths: Proprio_View_Helper_: Proprio/View/Helper/
Zend_View_Helper_:
Zend/View/Helper/:/home2/t1002046/application/views/helpers/' in /home2/t1002046/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php:412 

Stack trace:
#0 /home2/t1002046/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(1182): 
    Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('ServerURL') 
#1 /home2/t1002046/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(618): 
    Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'serverURL') 
#2 /home2/t1002046/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(344):
    Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('serverURL') 
#3 /home2/t1002046/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(6): 
    Zend_View_Abstract->__call('serverURL', Array) 
#4 /home2/t1002046/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(6): 
    Zend_View->serverURL() 
#5 /home2/t1002046/library/Zend/View.php(108):
    include('/home2/t1002046...') 
#6 /home2/t1002046/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(888):
    Zend_View->_run('/home2/t1002046...') 
#7 /home in /home2/t1002046/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 336
```

I don't know if I'm not loading something important on my application.ini, once it works fine on localhost, but the error says about 'Plugin by name 'ServerURL' and actually I don't now what's wrong or how to load the ServerURL. This ServerURL is located on my layout.phtml:

```
<base href="<?php echo $this->serverURL() . $this->baseURL()?>/" />
```

Follow my `application.ini`:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"

resources.locale.default = "pt_BR"
resources.locale.force = 1

autoloadernamespaces[] = "Proprio"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.plugins[ ] = "Proprio_Controller_Plugin_Acl"

resources.view.helperPath.Proprio_View_Helper = "Proprio/View/Helper"

; Layout
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"

; Banco de Dados
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_Mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = ""
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"

; habilita modules, desta forma (apenas =) o ZF dÃ¡ o new em modules
resources.modules = 

;cache
resources.cachemanager.default.frontend.options.lifetime = 7800
resources.cachemanager.default.backend.options.cache_dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/cache"

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Comment: What is the class name related to ServerUrl? and where is it located?

Answer (score 0):

If your localhost is Windows and your Server is Linux a common problem is that linux's file and folder names are case sensitive. Please check your file names and class names correspond to the folder structure. Hope that helps